# How can I modify text in admin bar?

Tags: admin-menu, admin-bar, user-registration

I am looking to change 'register' to 'join' in the wp admin bar for logged out users. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you explain more on this? These kind of questions make more sense with an image to explain it better

Comment: The admin bar doesn't display by default for non-logged in users.  What plugins/theme are you running that does?  Have you looked at that code to see how it's displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the meta bar where people can login or register? I'd recommend using jQuery, because if you make the change to the core, it'll be overwritten once you update it.

```
$('a[href*="register"]').text('join');
```

This basically states find an anchor tag where the href contains the word register. Once it finds it, it changes the inner text to 'join'.